# Android: Как на кнопке одновременно задействовать два сушателя

Tags: java, android, android-on-click, ontouchlistener

Возникла следующая проблема:

Имеется кнопка у которой необходимо обрабатывать два слушателя. Первый это `onTouchListener`, второй `onClickListener`. Код слушателя `onTouchListener()` ниже:

```
OnTouchListener dragt = new OnTouchListener()
     {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams par = (LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            switch(v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.button1:

                {
                    switch(event.getAction())
                    {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        {
                            par.topMargin = (int)event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight());
                            par.leftMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);
                            par.bottomMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);
                            par.rightMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);
                            v.setLayoutParams(par);
                            break;
                        }
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        {
                            par.height = 120;
                            par.width = 120;
                            par.topMargin = (int)event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight());
                            par.leftMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);
                            par.bottomMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);
                            par.rightMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);
                            v.setLayoutParams(par);
                            break;
                        }
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        {
                            par.height = 150;
                            par.width = 150;
                            v.setLayoutParams(par);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
     };
```

Мне же необходимо чтобы при обычном клике срабатывал `onClick()`. Назначал слушателя `onClickListener` - не работает(то есть онтач срабатывает, а онклик нет), назначал кнопке свойство 
    `android:onClick="knopka"`

Далее вызывал в активити:

```
public void knopka(View v) {
       System.out.println("Работай же!!!");
    }
```

Все равно не работает. Как еще сделать не представляю!

Comment: Попробуйте вернуть `false` - тогда сработает следующий за  `onTouchListener()` слушатель

Comment: @Barmaley спасибо большое!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как обычно, читаем [документацию](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html):

> *Returns*
>
> True if **the listener has consumed the event**, false otherwise.

Таким образом, как нетрудно догадаться, вам нужно возвращать из `OnTouchListener.onTouch` `false`, а не `true`.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Плохо видимо читаю! Спасибо и @Barmaley! Вы с ним прям одновременно мыслите) Он даже шустрее) Не зря карма больше.

Comment: Теперь проблема возникла с тем что на устройстве срабатывают оба поочереди! То есть я переммещаю кнопку отпускаю в нужном месте, и срабатывает onClick()

Comment: В `OnTouchListener.onTouch`, в случае, если событие `ACTION_MOVE` возвращайте `true`, в остальных случаях — `false`. Таким образом, если было перемещение кнопки, то до `OnClickListener` событие не дойдёт.